# How to find IP assigned to computer accessing internet "through" Ubuntu (20.04) desktop

Tags: networking, ssh, internet

I have a desktop running Ubuntu 20.04 that has two Ethernet ports on the motherboard NIC. One port is connected to the household router. The other port is connected to my Nvidia Jetson Nano. I am sharing the internet connection with the Jetson Nano through the Ubuntu desktop PC. In this situation, the Jetson Nano is (as far as I can tell) being dynamically assigned an IP address by my Ubuntu desktop.

I would like to be able to see the IP of the Jetson Nano while logged into the Ubuntu desktop via SSH. How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Does `ip a` not show the Nano in its results?

Comment: @mpboden in this case the router is not assigning the DHCP lease to Nano. The Ubuntu desktop is. The Nano is isolated in a different subnet.